# How can i make a function parameter that specifies the case of the text?

Tags: python

So in this make_title() function i need to make an additional third parameter which specifies the case of my title. When i call the print_title() , the third parameter within the brackets should define which case my output is going to be. Our teacher said we should use the string methods .upper() and .title(), but i don't know where te use them. Anyone has an idea? I feel like i'm stuck too long on something that should be pretty easy to understand. Thanks in advance :)

```
import os
import pdb

def make_title(title,sep='_',case):
    newtitle = title + '\n'+sep*len(title)
    return(newtitle)
   

def print_title(title,sep,case):
    r1 = make_title(title,sep,case)
    print(r1)


print_title('My name is John','=','upper')
```

Comment: A simple solution is to implement the logic you need with if statement. `if case == "upper": ` call `.upper()` where needed, etc. Programming is all about writing the logic you need your program to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows:

```
# string.upper()
my_name="john"
my_name.upper() # returns 'JOHN'
```

Same goes for title:

```
# string.title()
my_name="john"
my_name.title() # returns 'John'
```

Your function:

```
def my_case_assigner(title, sep, case):
    # Modify according to your assignment
    if case == 'upper':
        return title.upper()
    elif case == 'title':
        return title.title()
```